# How to check if file locked/used by other process NSIS

Tags: nsis

Hi I am writing nsis script for a patch installer. Before installer copies new files I need to check if any process is using the files I want to replace and I want rename those files to tmp and delete them on reboot. 
Is there any way installer can detect that if any process is using those files (in my case the files I am going to install are dlls).

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way in NSIS how to do this. But there are third party tools which can detect dlls used by certain process - maybe you could use them in your installer.

But my question is: Do you really need to detect this?

What about deleting files directly with **Delete /REBOOTOK file** command? (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.4.11)

If /REBOOTOK is specified and the file cannot be deleted then the file is deleted when the system reboots.